# Xamarin Forms | Use a Object on Different Pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, parameter-passing

I want to create an Android App with Xamarin.Forms.
I create an Object on the Mainpage. This object is a Collection of many other Objects.
My goal is to push this Collection-Object to another Page, and on this Page i want to add an Object to the Collection-Object. After this i want that the newly added Object is in the Collection on the MainPage.

I am Navigating between Pages with Push and Pop.
The YT Tutorials only work in one direction, so that i can see the object on the second page, but when i add an Object to the Collection, it isn't visible on the second Page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of *describing* your code, it is much more effective to actually **post** the relevant code.  Pages are just C# classes, and you should be able to pass objects between them like you can with any class

Answer (score 0):

The `Application` subclass has a static `Properties` dictionary which can be used to store data, in particular for use in the `OnStart`, `OnSleep`, and `OnResume` methods. This can be accessed from anywhere in your Xamarin.Forms code using `Application.Current.Properties`.

You could save it like :

```
ObservableCollection<object> objects;

Application.Current.Properties ["YourKey"] = objects;
```

then  get it :

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("YourKey"))
{
    ObservableCollection<object> objects = (User)Application.Current.Properties["YourKey"];
}
```

the more you could look at [Properties dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#properties-dictionary)